# Setting face colors in fiddle

Tags: three.js, jsfiddle

Looks like I can't set face colors in a fiddle

I am setting face colors like this

```
var face = new THREE.Face3 (inx1, inx3, inx2);
face.color = color;
face.ambient = color;
face.normal.set(0,0,-1);
geometry.faces.push (face);
```

The face and normals are reversed because I am casting shadows and the shadows don't work if the face isn't set this way. But I set double side faces :

```
var pMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, shininess: 100, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
```

The end result is that the faces are black

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LK84y/2/)

Exactly the same setup is working ok in local. (Well, I *think* that it is the same).
I just can't understand what is the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of three.js that comes "bundled" in jsfiddle is a bit too old. Try including the latest.

```
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LK84y/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the issue !  I wasn't aware of using anything needing a *modern* threejs release, by the way ...

Comment: `new THREE.Color(0.58, 0.58, 0.58)` that requires r66+ or so.